# Replace div with same div onclick with jQuery

Tags: jquery, replace, onclick, refresh, reload

I want to replace a `div` container with jQuery `onclick` on a button, but I don't know how to do this. I tried this:

```
jQuery(document).click(function() {
("#dynamic").load("single.php #partial_index");
});
```

But how do I replace it? Now it won't show up if I click on it (it does nothing), but that's normal I guess because I don't state replacing the div. Is there any change I can get this work?

I want to replace a div with an ID called test if I click on the button dynamic. I want it to be replaced by single.php #partial_index. The button does nothing now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#dynamic").click(function() {
   $('#test').replaceWith($('#partial_index'));
});
```

Comment: Nope, it says `missing ) after argument list

</script>`

Comment: I have edited my answer to close the braces.. see if you have closed the braces properly

Answer (score 3):

First, always make sure your primary code is INSIDE the DOM ready structure, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // This fires when the DOM has loaded (thus all your link(stylesheet) and script includes at the very least
});
```

Inside your function, I see you using ('#dynamic'), wheras it is missing the $ jQuery global or the jQuery namespace itself, use it like so:

```
jQuery('#dynamic');
```

Or

```
$('#dynamic');
```

Next, you've got a button you'd want to use to replace content inside a div?

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $('#dynamic').load('single.php#partial_index');
});
```

You can also REPLACE your content with a new element, like so:

```
$('#dynamic').replaceWith($('<div>I am a new jQuery dynamic element!</div>'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried  this:

`<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('button').click(function() {
jQuery('#dynamic').replaceWith(jQuery('<div>I am a new jQuery dynamic element!</div>'));
})});
</script>`

But it does nothing?

Answer (score 1):

What this code does now is bind a click handler to the document. When the document is clicked, it loads `single.php #partial_index` into the `#dynamic` element (though it's missing the `$`: `$('#dynamic')`.

Here's what I think you want:

```
$('#dynamic').click(function() {
    $('#test').load("single.php #partial_index");
});
```

Comment: It is no answer to my question. It doesn't replace a thing.

Comment: Here's how I understand what you want: "When I click the element with the id of 'dynamic', fetch 'single.php' (only the contents of the element with id 'partial_index') and put that content in the div with the id of 'test'". Am I understanding incorrectly?

Comment: I want to replace test with partial_index, but the way you understood would work too. Anyhow, this was just a small part of a different question. Here is the actual question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751511/partially-refresh-post-list-in-wordpress

Answer (score 1):

Untested but something like this should work

```
$("#dynamic").click(function() {
    $("<div />").attr("id", "#partial_index").load("single.php #partial_index", function(data){
         var newDiv = $(this).html(data);
         $('#test').replaceWith(newDiv)  
     })
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer James, but nothing is happening either.